# How can I "grep" matching a "comment" string?

Tags: bash, shell, file, grep, comments

I've a `README.md` file with this text (notice the comment):

```
[//]: # (Template README)

This is my file bla bla bla
```

Doing this:

```
readme_file=./README.md

if grep -q "[//]: # (Template README)" "$readme_file"; then
  echo "match"
fi
```

Doesn't match the string.

Why? How can I match it?

Comment: either `grep -F` or escape the []: `grep -q "\[//\]: # (Template README)" "$readme_file"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -F` for that.

```
grep -F "[//]: # (Template README)" README.md
```

`-F` interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings (i.e. force grep to behave as fgrep).